# Three conditions on one column of table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Following is script of sample Table

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID int)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1), (2), (NULL), (3), (NULL), (1)
```

I want three condition on column `ID`

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE ID -- Can't figure out
```

1. If User want all rows
2. If user want rows where ID is NULL
3. If user want rows where ID is NOT NULL

I can do this by putting my query in string but In long query there is only one condition like this so I don't want to put all query in string.

EDIT: In response to @Tim Schmelter.
My apologies that I could not make my point clear. User will select from front end that either s/he want to all rows only rows where ID is given or rows where ID is not given

In long query one condition is like this

```
@id INT // Value from front end like 'All', 'Products', 'No Products'
WHERE ID = @ID // Here I can't figure out that how to use one of three conditions
```

Please let me know If I am still unable to explain my question. I will try again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present to user the choices(e.g. radio button), then pass the chosen option's value to database like :

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE 
   (@Option = 1)
   OR (@Option = 2 AND ID IS NULL)
   OR (@Option = 3 AND ID IS NOT NULL)
```

OR can kill performance though, SQL Server(or any RDBMS for that matter) doesn't do short-circuit. CASE WHEN can *somewhat* force short-circuit

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE 
   CASE @Option
   WHEN 1 THEN 1
   WHEN 2 THEN 
          CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 1 END
   WHEN 3 THEN
          CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END
   END = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe i've misunderstood your requirement, isn't it that easy?

```
-- 1.) If User want all rows 
SELECT * FROM @tbl 

-- 2.) If user want rows where ID is NULL
SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE ID IS NULL

-- 3.) If user want rows where ID is NOT NULL
SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
```

**Edit**: So you want to use a parameter to filter accordingly, have a look:

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE   @FilterID = 1                      -- returns all rows
OR    ( @FilterID = 2 AND ID IS NULL)      -- returns all null-rows
OR    ( @FilterID = 3 AND ID IS NOT NULL)  -- returns all not null rows
```

You can also use `CASE` in where clause, although [it is not recommended](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Tim, so nice of you!

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem: note that the `case` approach might be less efficient than boolean logic, see last link above.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are some cases that `case` approach can do the job well. case in point: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29531/2. At first I'm thinking doing queries in a pure boolean approach(e.g. `(@Option = 1 AND Blah = Bleh) OR (@Option = 2 THEN Hah = Heh)`) as boolean approach can easily translate well to ORM language(Linq, HQL and whatnot), whereas using `CASE WHEN` has no analogous to ORM language. Well I guess there's a place and time for purity and pragmatism

Comment: An `OR` in a join on large tables is incomparable and will result in expensive [nested loop joins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/26/679319.aspx). But you're right, it depends on the use case and key factors.