# How to use "IN" in CASE on SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to accomplish the following from `case when`

```
If @chk='Y'  
    Select * From Table1 Where Column1=@Value  
Else If (@chk='N')
    Select * From Table1 Where Column1 In (Select column2 from Table2)
```

I think it may be something like:

```
 Select * 
 From Table1 
 Where 
    Case  When @chk='Y' Then
        Column1=@Value
    Else
        Column1 In (Select column2 from Table2)
 End
```

I know there are alternative solutions other than `Case When`. But is it possible to do this using `Case when`?

Comment: They are two different tables, is that correct?

Comment: Table1 and Table2 are different tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CASE is an expression that returns a single value. It is not used for control of flow.

```
WHERE (Column1 = @Value AND @chk = 'Y')
OR (@chk <> 'Y' AND Column1 IN (SELECT column2 FROM table2));
```

Answer (score 5):

`CASE` is used for inline evaluation of expressions.  It's not really for dynamic `WHERE` clauses.

The solution for what you are asking is to use a `WHERE` clause grouped by parentheses:

```
 Select * From Table1 
 Where 
 (@chk='Y' AND Column1=@Value)
 OR
 (@chk <> 'Y' AND Column1 In (Select column2 from Table2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do it with `CASE WHEN` and it could be ideal. I answered a similar question( [Three conditions on one column of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736036/three-conditions-on-one-column-of-table/10736180#10736180) ) to this question

```
Select * From Table1 
Where 
   CASE @Chk
   WHEN 'Y' THEN
        CASE WHEN Column1=@Value THEN 1 END 
   WHEN 'N' THEN
        CASE WHEN Column1 In (Select column2 from Table2) THEN 1 END
   END = 1
```

`CASE` can *somewhat* force short-circuit expression.

Case in point why `OR` should be avoided: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29531/2

Given these two functionally identical queries:

```
-- using CASE WHEN to convince your RDBMS to short-circuit things:
select count(*)
from usermessages um
join "user" u    
on
(case when um.friendId = 1 then um.sourceUserId else um.friendId end) = u.userId;


-- pure boolean approach, RDBMS can't short-circuit the OR expression
select count(*)
from usermessages um
join "user" u    
on 
(um.friendId = 1 and um.sourceUserId = u.userId)
or 
(um.friendId = u.userId);
```

Given the sample data from http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29531/2, the first query took only 88 milliseconds, while the second query took 4.7 seconds.  The difference in speed is very perceivable by the users.

This is not a hard and fast rule, you must still check how your RDBMS will actually execute your queries. Your RDBMS may still not do your bidding(short-circuit) when using `CASE WHEN`. The best rule still is to profile your queries

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use Case statements in WHERE clauses.  They way you would do it is:

```
Select *
From Table1
Where (Case When @chk='Y' and Column1=@Value the 'Y'
            Else Column1 In (Select column2 from Table2)
       End) = 'Y'
```

Normally, you don't want to do this, primarily for aesthetic reasons.  That said, there may be cases where the code written with a case is more readable than with the corresponding logic in the where.  In fact, this might be such a case.

More importantly, though, is the situation where you want to short circuit for performance reasons or syntax.  Using the WHERE clause pretty much guarantees evaluation of the subquery.  It is possible it won't be executed using the CASE.

Errors are another situation.  The following can generate a SQL type error when the column is not numeric, because SQL does not guarantee the ordering of clauses in a WHERE:

```
where isnumeric(val) = 1 and cast(val to float) < 100.0
```

On the other hand, the following works:

```
where (case when isnumeric(val) = 1 then cast(val to float) end) < 100.0
```

Personally, when faced with this situation, I prefer to put the case in a subquery, so the WHERE would contain a column name.